# How can I get Windows to properly identify my monitors?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a problem where my monitors are no longer recognized in the correct order by Windows using the "Identify" feature on the Screen Resolution control panel.

[image: huge tri-mon pic]

The above screenshot is the correct orientation that matches my physical monitor setup, but the numbers in the preview panel (the tiny ones) which are 1,2,3 do not match the numbers in the "Identify" mode (the large numbers on each monitor) which are 3,1,2.

Is there a way to fix this so that the numbers match the monitor? It takes 5 minutes to figure it out sometimes because it is so confusing.

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro (x64) on an nVidia GeForce GTX 970 driver version 353.06. I also use Display Fusion to control my wallpapers.

Comment: Does the mouse move between them as per the screenshot or does it move according to how the Windows thinks they are set. I would check to see if you haven't got any multi-monitor settings activated in Display Fusion running by accident.

Comment: The mouse moves in the correct orientation in that screenshot. If I arrange the monitors in order of 3, 1, 2 as the large number suggest it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use your screenshot as an example, just drag&drop in the circled area, then click Apply.

---

Update: No idea about display fusion though, my answer is how Windows Multi-monitor works by default.

[image]

Comment: This does not fix the problem. If I were to arrange the monitors in order of 3,1,2 as the screenshot I posted suggest, they would be in the incorrect order.